# process in-app apple receipt with java

Tags: java, iphone, json, in-app-purchase

I am using a java backend. After a user performs an in-app purchase, the front-end sends me the receipt. In turn, I am to send the receipt to apple for confirmation; then apple is to decode the receipt and send me back a JSON dictionary. My question is about sending the receipt back to apple so that I may get the json response. I am using the code below. But I keep getting {"status":21002} from apple and something about "Invalid cookie header". Any ideas how to solve this?

```
    String url = "https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt";
    DefaultHttpClient client = null;
    try {
        String input = IOUtils.toString(is);
        log.info("THE INPUTSTREAM: " + input);
        JSONObject receipt = new JSONObject();
        receipt.put("receipt-data", input);

        client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(receipt.toString());
        entity.setContentType("application/json");
        post.setEntity(entity);
        HttpClientParams.setRedirecting(post.getParams(), false);

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        if (300 <= response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("No response from iTune store. status code: " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        }

        if (null == response.getEntity()) {
            log.info("Response is null");
            throw new Exception("Response is null");
        }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        for (String line; null != (line = reader.readLine());) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
        log.info("THE JSON" + json);
//Then work with json below

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new WebApplicationException(Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(e.getMessage()).build());
    } finally {
        if (null != client) {
            client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No need cookie I think? try

```
HttpClientParams.setCookiePolicy(client.getParams(), CookiePolicy.IGNORE_COOKIES);
```